# send files to a website through a 'browse files' on pc

Tags: python, parsing, web, dryscrape

I'm browsing through a website using dryscrape in python and i need to upload a file to this site. But there is only one way of doing it, that is clicking in a button and browse into my files and select the one i want. How can i do it with python? i would appreciate if someone could help me using dryscrape too, but i'm accepting all answers.

heres the example image:
[image: IMG]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). I tested this code and it works.

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://example.com/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
driver.get(url)

input_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=\"file\"]")

# absolute path to file
abs_file_path = "/Users/foo/Downloads/bar.png"
input_element.send_keys(abs_file_path)

sleep(5)

driver.quit()
```

Resources

- [Selenium python](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)
- [Chrome driver download](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Comment: Thanks bro, i forgot about selenium! :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are searching for the answer in dryscrape i translated the selenium code to dryscrape:

```
element = sessin.at_xpath("xpath...") # Session is a dryscrape session
# The xpath is from the button like the one in the image "Browse..."
element.set("fullpath")
```

just as simple as it is.